# Display sbt settings from command line

Tags: sbt

Is there a way of displaying the sbt settings from the command line?

Things like where it's picking up it's repositories file from, and credentials?

Comment: You should clarify your question, give more concrete examples of what you want and what you've tried (like searching documentation and running some commands). Otherwise the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from sbt prompt
`inspect credentials`, `inspect resolvers`
or
sbt 'inspect resolvers'...
or use show instead of inspect if you just want to see setting value
There is roughly 500 settings and tasks in sbt build. So, you probably do not want to display all of them